# How to rename all interfaces from a declaration files

Tags: typescript

I would like to rename all my interfaces that come from a declaration file of a lib to not be camelCase but Kebab case.
The idea in the end is to have a template literal in kebab-case of all interfaces name that could match any interface name

```js
//lib.d.ts
export interface AccessBoostWords {
  words?: string;
}

export interface AccountUpdate {
  type: 'account-update';
}
...
}
```

```js
// src/global.d.ts
import * as libExports from 'lib';

declare global {
    // Étendez le namespace avec les exports de lib
    export import API = libExports;
}

export = API;
```

I tried with `keyof typeof` etc but it always return never .. any idea?